# Does 'Rows per batch' is SSIS OLE DB destination help reducing locking?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

There is an option called 'Rows per batch' in OLE DB Destination, which, when specified, pulls a certain amount of rows within a batch, otherwise, pull all rows in the source in one batch.

Question: If my source and/or targer server are all highly OLTP database, will setting a low number on this parameter (for eg, 10k or 50k) help reducing lock escalation chance, so that the loading process can make minimal impact on either of the databases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Rows per batch" is actually more for tuning your data flow. By calculating the maximum width of a row, in bytes, and then dividing the default buffer size (the default is 10MB), you will get the number of rows you can insert in one "batch" without spilling the data out to tempdb or your buffer disk (depending if you set a specific location for you temp buffer). While keeping your data flow completely in memory and not needing to spill to disk, you'll keep your data transfer moving as quickly as possible.

The "Table Lock" option in the OLE DB Destination is what tells the server to lock the table or not.

Answer (score 0):

In general the answer is: yes.
It also depends on the processing speed of the rows and the overhead per batch.
If your transaction with all the rows in a batch takes to long, consider splitting up. But splitting it up in too small batches can also yield performance problems.

The best way is to test and find the sweetspot.